# Android touch and scroll Listview

Tags: android

I have a custom listview in my app in which the list items are draggable and can be dropped on another position on the listview itself.Now my problem is, I want to Scroll the listview. I tried using onIntercept touch event, but only the touch event happens. I can't able to scroll, Can somebody suggest me an idea on how to achieve this thing...

Comment: Check if motioEvent action is ACTION_MOVE and if it is return false so the touch event will be passed to the other elements in the Hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah...i tried with that but it wont works as i expected...i am trying now using custom scrollview class to enable auto scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating layout for your `ListItem` as depicted below:

[image]

Please let us know in case this layout doesn't suit your requirement.

Comment: Firstly thanks!...It is similar to what I am trying to do but, I will try to rearrange using drag and drop, and scroll using scroll bars on the right side, not only scroll bars it can be anything but the logic should be same.

Answer (score 0):

I got the flat position using pointToPosition method and supplied it dynamically to smoothScrollToPosition method,

```
    int flatPos=pointToPosition(flatx, flaty);

    super.smoothScrollToPosition(flatPos);
```

Answer (score -1):

You might consider instead using Carl A. Bauer's open-source [`DragSortListView` library](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). It handles drag-to-sort even on older Android versions that don't have drag-and-drop, while letting you still scroll the list. There are two techniques you can use for this in particular: you can use a drag handle (like the one Gagan drew) to sort items, and let dragging anywhere else scroll the list; or you can let dragging scroll the list, and long-press an item to pick it up and rearrange it. It's very flexible about handling taps and drags, so there are more possibilities too.

Full disclosure: As a user of the library, I've also contributed to it, but I have no financial interest in people using it, and no other connection with the author.